# biztalk wcf adapter pack

Tags: biztalk, adapter

Ive installed the wcf adapters for biztalk 2006 R2, but when I try to create a new adapter the new adapters are not showing in the dropdown list.
After a bit of digging about online I installed both x64 and x86 packs but still no sign of them.
Am I missing something else?

thanks

DW

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you follow the complete installation instructions

> http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/6/a/e6a2d71d-b4bb-4c7c-959d-0b0f14b6e5df/InstallationGuide.htm

Don't these adapters (SAP, Siebel, Oracle and SQL) show up as bindings for the WCF-Custom adapter? If so, you won't have an adapter handler to add.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a handler for the adapters?

[How to Create an Adapter Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa547106%28BTS.20%29.aspx)