# Why can i promote property fields in BizTalk 2006 but distinguished fields are disabled?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk2006r2

I have a very strange behaviour in the Show Promotions Dialog in BizTalk 2006. It allows me to promote property fields:

[image: Property Fields Promotion in BizTalk 2006]

But distinguished fields are disabled:

[image: Distinguished Fields Promotion in BizTalk 2006]

Any thoughts?

---

This is the XML Schema generated by the SQL Transport Schema Generation Wizard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
<xs:schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns="http://ExecutionPlanner.InitializeStep" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://ExecutionPlanner.InitializeStep" version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <msbtssql:sqlScript value="exec [InitizializeStep] @ORCHESTRATION_NAME=" ", @PROVIDER_NAME=" ", @STEP_NAME=" "" xmlns:msbtssql="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" /> 
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Step">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:element name="OrchestrationID" type="OrchestrationIDType" />
        <xs:element name="Message" type="MessageType" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="OrchestrationIDType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string" />
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="MessageType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string" />
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Post your schema please. My suspicion is that OrchestrationID is a complex type

Comment: Yep, it's a complex type created by the SQL Adapter. Is that not supported?

Comment: You can only distinguish simple types. Also why are you using SQL adapter? It's depricated.

Comment: We are still using BizTalk 2006 and can't migrate to BizTalk 2010 and WCF-SQL Adapter until late 2013.

Comment: 2006R2 supports WCF-Sql no? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700383/biztalk-wcf-adapter-pack

Comment: Yes, BizTalk 2006R2 support WCF-SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your schema to change the OrchestrationID field from a Record to a Field Element. Only Elements and Attributes can be distinguished.

This usually entails deleting the existing Record element, then re-creating an Element with the same name, as Visual Studio wont allow changing an xml node's type.  However, you can get around this by opening the xsd file using the XML (Text) Editor using the 'Open With...' option.

Comment: OrchestrationID is an Element, but it's a Complex Type. I posted the schema, so you can look a it. Thanks for your help.